# Look-up another row based on current row in in the same table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

Suppose that I have a table with three columns:

1. EventID (PK)
2. TagName
3. TagValue

I need to create a query that results in something like:

1. EventID
2. TagName
3. TagValue
4. PreviousConditionTag
5. PreviousConditionValue

Where PreviousConditionTag/Value is from TagName and TagValue of a previous row (when ordered by EventID).

In a simpler version of this problem, PreviousConditionTag was always the same as TagName - that is, I only needed to retrieve the previous value for the current TagName. I solved this using Oracle's LAG analytic function, partitioning by the TagName.

However, I now need to perform something similar but for cases where PreviousConditionTag is an arbitrary tag related to TagName by another table where the relation between TagName and PreviousConditionTag is not one-to-one.

For example, if a given row has a TagName of "ABC", the relation table may say that I need to look-up the previous value of either "IJK" or "XYZ".

I was able to come up with this logic in an Oracle function that does a SELECT against the same table and looks for MAX(EventID) that matches the criteria. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE EventID = (
    SELECT MAX(EventID) FROM MyTable WHERE TagName IN (
        SELECT ConditionTagName FROM ConditionMappingTable WHERE TagName = [CurrentTagName]
    )
) AND EventID <= [CurrentEventId]
```

However, as you can imagine, since this query is executed in a function for every row of MyTable, I am concerned about its performance.

I was trying to think of a way to use Oracle's LAG analytic again, but I wasn't sure how to come up with the PARTITION clause for it, since the partitions appear to overlap. (e.g. Tag ABC needs to look at IJK and XYZ, and Tag DEF needs to look at IJK and UVW)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rewritten form of the answer, now that I understand it better.

You want to look up overlapping sets of tags and still get the previous event id.  The idea is the following:

1. Add to the mapping table the identity for all Current Tags (so Current Tag = Condition Tag)
2. Join in the mapping table based on the *condition* tag, to get the current tags that match.  So, the rows are getting relabeled with the "current" tag they match, and you can use this for the lag.
3. Get the most recent EventId based on the lag logic, partitioning by the *Current* Tag.
4. Select the results where the Current and Condition tags are the same.

   ```
   select t.*
   from (select t.*, mt.CurrentTagName, mt.ConditionTagName,
            lag(EventId, 1, NULL)
            over (partition by mt.CurrentTagName
                  order by EventId)
     from t join
          (select CurrentTagName, ConditionTagName
           from ((select CurrentTagName, ConditionTagName
                  from ConditionMappingTable mt
                 ) union all
                 (select distinct CurrentTagName, CurrentTagName
                  from ConditionMappingTable mt
                 )
                ) mt
          )
          on mt.ConditionTagName = t.tagname
    ) t
   on CurrentTagName = ConditionTagName
   ```

This may seem counterintuive, because you are looking things up backwards, by the condition rather than the current.  And, you are multiplying the number of rows being processed.  However, it may still be faster than the join solution you were using.

Comment: What is the purpose of the offset in this case? The Oracle LAG() analytic has an offset I can specify, and in the simple case where I just needed the previous value for a given tag, the offset was 1. In this case the offset is still technically "1", but the partitions aren't as straight-forward. In the raw data, the previous tag I am looking for could have occurred any number of rows prior (it doesn't always occur immediately before the current row when ordered by event id).

Comment: My apologies. I better undersand the question, and re-answered it.  I might have gotten the ConditionTagName and CurrentTagName backwards.

Comment: No problem, thanks for taking a second look! Your suggestion of doing the look-up backwards by the condition rather than the current value appears to make a big difference. I rewrote my query to do this and it completes in less than a second now, as opposed to maybe 5 or 6 seconds before. Thanks for your help!